# How to roll back an update of a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, updates, firefox-extensions, undo

Today I updated Adblock Plus addon from v1.2 to v1.3. After restarting Firefox, I realized that Adblock Plus no more blocks ads no matter if I activate or deactivate it. This seems to be a buggy version (e.g. there are some blank lines in its context menu, preferences menu can't be displayed, etc.). The previous version was fine.

How can I roll back a Firefox addon to its previous version?

My Firefox version is 3.6.11 and I'm on Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just uninstall the add on and reinstall the older version. I think it would be a little buggy to try to "roll back" to the previous version if it is even possible.

UPDATE: I found that on this link https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6262 people were also having the same problem and someone sent an update at 11:18 EST. Try installing the update. This should fix everything.

-Good Luck

Comment: No problem... Also just so that everyone who reads this post knows, which one did you do? (i.e. uninstall and install older version, or install update)

Comment: The problem is present on my work PC, and I'm at home at the moment. Tomorrow I'll try what you suggest and drop a line here.

Comment: Installing the update (1.3.1) on that link solved the problem.